# Is it possible to retroactively add history that would have been there if an svn cp had been performed instead of a cp?

Tags: svn

I have a project with one directory that was originally (several hundred commits ago) copied verbatim from another directory, but svn cp wasn't used so there's a disconnect in history. Is it possible to connect the two directories at the initial copy point now, or is it too late?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me guess what you're talking about:

- Directory `foo` is in Subversion
- In revision #100, someone copied `foo` to `bar`
- They then added `bar` to the repository and did a commit and created revision #101.
- Now Subversion is at revision #2302.

What you want to do is somehow go back in history back to revision #100, and redo the copy and add with a true `svn copy`. That way, you can see the history of bar that it was copied from foo.

There might be a way of doing an `svnadmin dump` of the repository, and then an `svnadmin load`.

You need to create a dump of revisions 1 to 100 and another dump of 102 to head. You load in revisions 1 to 100 into the repository. Then you do your `svn copy` and commit revision 101. Finally, you load in revisions 102 to head into the repository.

That, in theory, should fix the issue. I have never done this particular fix, but I've done other selective dump and loads where I changed the history.

Comment: This seems exactly what I'm looking for. Kind of surprised it's possible, but nice that you need to have svnadmin access.

Answer (score 1):

Move your unversioned directory out of the way, then `svn cp` from the older revision of the original directory to the new one.  You can use `@<revision-number>` after the name of the source directory in the `svn cp` command to specify the revision. Then copy your changes on top of the now version-controlled copy and commit them.

Here's a contrived example:

```
$ cd working-copy
$ ls -R
.:
copy-of-original  original

./copy-of-original:
bar  foo

./original:
bar  foo
$ svn info original
Path: original
URL: file:///home/gardnerm/repo/original
Repository Root: file:///home/gardnerm/repo
Repository UUID: 6124f37b-b9bf-4d8a-906d-c4015c6f74ad
Revision: 2
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: gardnerm
Last Changed Rev: 2
Last Changed Date: 2011-05-04 19:48:00 -0400 (Wed, 04 May 2011)
$ svn info copy-of-original
copy-of-original:  (Not a versioned resource)

svn: A problem occurred; see other errors for details
$ mv copy-of-original backup-copy
$ svn cp original@1 copy-of-original   ## this is a copy from a previous revision
A    copy-of-original/foo
A    copy-of-original/bar
Updated to revision 1.
A         copy-of-original
$ svn commit -m 'copying from original r1'
Adding         copy-of-original

Committed revision 3.
$ cp -r backup-copy/* copy-of-original  ## bringing up to date
$ svn commit -m 'updating copy with latest changes'
Sending        copy-of-original/bar
Sending        copy-of-original/foo
Transmitting file data ..
Committed revision 4.
$ rm -r backup-copy
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I need. copy-of-original IS a versioned resource. original was copied over to copy-of-original then svn add'd, rather than just svn cp'ing original in the first place. On top of that, both original and copy-of-original have changed since that initial copying.